# Unable to retrieve cancelledOccurences from recurring event using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

When I query the Microsoft Graph API for event instances (graphClient.Me.Events[ExternalID].Instances), all event instances are returned.

In addition, instances that have been changed and are now "exceptions" are also returned.

However, instances that have been deleted or cancelled are not returned.

Is there any way to get instances that been deleted or cancelled?

Comment: I am in the exact same situation as yours. Were you able to find the solution for that? I am also getting all the remaining occurrences within the original timespan, without any trace of the deleted occurrence.